# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, digital-ocean

Getting an error stating that the database is unknown for my user even though it exists and is spelled correctly. I have granted them all permissions on the db, I can access it through the mysql command line in my server and I can access it through mysql workbench but when trying to access it with pdo in my api. I as well cannot create new schemas with the user.

I checked the User, Host from mysql.user and it shows that the user has % and localhost. I commented out bind-address in mysqld.cnf and created my user like so.

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword';
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

My pdo connection

```
<?php
class Database{
    private $host = "127.0.0.1";
    private $db_name = "casinoCheckList";
    private $username = "user";
    private $password = "myPassword";
    public $conn;

    public function getConnection(){

        $this->conn = null;
        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try `SHOW GRANTS;` when you are logged in as user. It will show what it thinks your privileges are. Note that user@localhost is different from user@%. It might be that the latter has privileges, but user@localhost does not.

Comment: It shows. 

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `casinoChecklist`.* TO 'user'@'localhost'`

casinoChecklist is my db name.

Comment: Updated to include how I'm connecting with pdo

Comment: Try "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1". The latter will use an IP connection, the former will use sockets.

Comment: Same error when I use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I have also tried using root but get Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'