# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049]

Tags: php, sql, json, phpmyadmin

Im currently setting up my DB connection in a case project, and gets "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049]" - message.

I've double checked the credentials about 10 times, and can't understand why I get the error.

My direct thought is that it has something to the port:8080 to do since my server is set up on localhost:8080, but I can't find any solution to the problem.

```
// DB Parameters
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $db_name = 'carshop'; 
    private $username = 'root'; 
    private $password = ''; 
    private $conn;
```

This is my params that I put into this line of code

```
$this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname= ' . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
```

The same setup up of credentials has worked before on earlier databases, but now I can't manage to get it to work.
Do you goys see or know anything that I don't?

Comment: Try removing the space after the `=` in `dbname= '`

Comment: already read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021301/sqlstatehy000-1049-unknown-database-pdo ?

Comment: Try to specify the port in the dsn, swapping the host and dbname positions in the dsn and removing the space after `dbname=`.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Comment: debugging this type of issue can be a pain... I always have a separate SQL IDE available that I can use to check the Mysql Database stuff. I use HeidiSQL IDE.  This allows me to test connection, tables etc. After that I get the database working in that. I can then start to understand where the issues are with the PHP setup. I will state that the DSN really needs to be correct as regards spaces and lettercase! You are dealing with very pedantic systems. The DSN Must match exactly the database parameters and the DSN specification. The PHP drivers are specific - no extra spaces anywhere!

Comment: Thank you guys! Managed to fix the issue with the help from your eyes and knowledge!